How do you systematically differentiate one graph from another?
Let's establish some rules and definitions first.
A graph is a set of points, often called nodes, that are connected by lines, often called edges. One graph is considered to be the same as another if you can't get it to look like another. You're allowed to shift nodes, rotate and reflect graphs, and move nodes to the other side of edges. You're not allowed to add nodes, remove nodes, add edges, or remove edges. All the nodes and edges are colored the same color.
One pretty trivial way you could attempt to do this is by simply counting the number of nodes and edges. But, as you can see from the 2 graphs shown below, that doesn't quite work.

(Sorry to anyone seeing these images who has OCD.) As you can see, both graphs have 4 edges and 4 nodes, but are obviously distinct from one another. So we need a different type of analysis to tell 1 graph from another.
What if we counted all the edges each node connected to and listed them from least to greatest? The graph in the upper left would be called 2-2-2-2. The graph in the upper right would be called 1-2-2-3. However, this doesn't always work either. Take a look at the 2 graphs below.

Both of these graphs would be labeled as 1-1-1-1-1-1-2-4-4. So how do you do it? How do you systematically distinguish 2 graphs from one another?

Welcome to Math SE. The technical term for your question is the graph isomorphism problem.

Also the list of numbers you are talking about at the end is called degree sequence, and as you have shown, it’s not enough to distinguish non-isomorphic graphs

adjacency matrix

If you want to compare two generic graphs, then as Misha Lavrov answered in the post K B Dave linked, there's no easy method. But if there are restrictions on the types of graphs you're looking at, then perhaps a customized algorithm could be developed for just those kind of graphs.
